# How to wait till 2nd user's post and plug that post to 1st user

Tags: node.js, express, mqtt

I have a operating MQTT broker and client. Once I publish a command to MQTT client, the client executes the command locally and uploads the output to an api endpoint. I'm offering the command from the same api end point

```
command input end 
{post} http://myhost/deviceId/cmd
{
   "command":"ls -lah"
}
```

then the controller publish this command into MQTT client

then the device receives the command via MQTT client then the device executes the command then uploads to

```
command result input end
{post} http://myhost/deviceId/cmdout

{
  "output": "......"
}
```

What I want is the server to wait till the device sends the output and then plug the input from cmdout to previous user request.So user have interactive shell experience.

API written with nodejs

Any idea how should implement this without storing to a database ?

Comment: HTTP is synchronous, MQTT is asynchronous trying to mix the 2 does not work well. If possible take the HTTP out of the loop and use MQTT to publish/subscribe directly from the UI (this can be MQTT over Websockets if it's a HTML page)